# Convert Variant Call Format (VCF) file to CSV using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm trying to convert this vcf file to csv using  a python library but i have no result, no library is working, or M not really familiar with them and don't really know how to use them, I tried Pyvcf, unvcf and recently panda, but no result.

the vcf file is located in 'C:/Users/lazra/Downloads/300C_filtered_snps_final.ann (1).vcf'

tried this :

```
import vcf
import csv

# Open the VCF file
vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open('C:/Users/lazra/Downloads/300C_filtered_snps_final.ann (1).vcf', 'r'))

# Write the header row
csv_writer.writerow(['CHROM', 'POS', 'ID', 'REF', 'ALT', 'QUAL', 'FILTER'])

# Write each variant as a row in the CSV file
for record in vcf_reader:
    print(record)
```

I get this error :

```
  File "<tmp 2>", line 4
    Open the VCF file
         ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

then tried this :

```
import pandas as pd

# read in CSV file, skipping over any problematic lines
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/lazra/Downloads/300C_filtered_snps_final.ann (1).vcf', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)

# write DataFrame to CSV file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

I get this printed out

```
                                                      0
0                                                     \
1                                                     \
2                                                     \
3                                                     \
4                                                     \
...                                                 ...
3151  10,88897920,\.\,\C\,\T\,37.32,\PASS\,\AC=2;AF=...
3152  10,89417950,\.\,\C\,\A\,37.32,\PASS\,\AC=2;AF=...
3153  10,89623716,\.\,\G\,\A\,2590.64,\PASS\,\AC=1;A...
3154  10,89623901,\.\,\G\,\C\,12621.06,\PASS\,\AC=2;...
3155  10,89653686,\.\,\A\,\G\,1161.64,\PASS\,\AC=1;A...
```

get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lazra\onedrive\bureau\tests\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    vcf_df = pd.DataFrame({'chrom': vcf[0], 'pos': vcf[1], 'id': vcf[2], 'ref': vcf[3], 'alt': vcf[4], 'qual': vcf[5], 'filter': vcf[6], 'info': vcf[7]})
  File "C:\Users\lazra\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3807, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\lazra\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1
```

you can see in the printed data, the separator is a comma ',' but when I replace \t with comma i get another error:

```
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1973, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 135, saw 84
```

as for unvcf the documentation couldn't help me on writing a working code

Comment: the first lines in the data printed are empty because they are comments, data starts from row 134, and row 133 is the header of the sheet

Comment: If you are not using any information from the INFO, FORMAT, SAMPLE(s) columns you  got a TSV file with 133/4 extra top lines. You defined the header already so you can skip lines starting with # and readjust the seven leftmost columns.

Comment: can you provide a code that illustrate what ou said

Comment: vcf_header = ['CHROM', 'POS', 'ID', 'REF', 'ALT', 'QUAL', 'FILTER'] 
usable_cols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
pd.read_csv("your_file_path", sep="\t", comment="#", usecols=usable_cols, header=vcf_header)